# Total visitor counter to my existing counter for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a simple visitor counter without MySQL in a WordPress plugin. To achieve this I make a simple text `visitor.db` where store visitor ip for a while and show the total number of IPs as current online visitor and after a time period the history log delete. But now I want to implement from that `visitor.db` to save them `another.db` where it count total visitor till today. Is it possible?

If I count while loop ? how can I save it to `another.db`

```
$counter = 0;
while(..) {
      $counter++; 
}

echo $counter;
```

For example now it show `Online : 70` 
But I want to achieve `Total : 145875458 Online : 70` something like this

```
define('VISITOR_DATA_PATH',plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ));
$dbfile = VISITOR_DATA_PATH . "visitors.db"; 
$expire = 300; // average time in seconds to consider someone online before removing from the list

if(!file_exists($dbfile)) {
    die("Error: Data file " . $dbfile . " NOT FOUND!");
}

if(!is_writable($dbfile)) {
    die("Error: Data file " . $dbfile . " is NOT writable! Please CHMOD it to 666!");
}

 function getIPs() {
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    elseif(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else $ip = "0";
    return $ip;
}

function CountVisitors() {
    global $dbfile, $expire;
    $cur_ip = getIPs();
    $cur_time = time();
    $dbary_new = array();

    $dbary = unserialize(file_get_contents($dbfile));
    if(is_array($dbary)) {
        while(list($user_ip, $user_time) = each($dbary)) {
            if(($user_ip != $cur_ip) && (($user_time + $expire) > $cur_time)) {
                $dbary_new[$user_ip] = $user_time;
            }
        }
    }
    $dbary_new[$cur_ip] = $cur_time; // add record for current user

    $fp = fopen($dbfile, "w");
    fputs($fp, serialize($dbary_new));
    fclose($fp);

    $out = sprintf("%3d", count($dbary_new)); // format the result to display 3 digits with leading 0's
    return $out;
}

function visitor_counter_shrocode(){
    $visitors_online = CountVisitors();

    ob_start();
    $output='<span> Online: <b>'.$visitors_online.'</b></span>';
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('onlinevisitor','visitor_counter_shrocode');
```